# Kotlin Exposed: How to create prepared statement or avoid SQL Injection?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I use Kotlin Exposed to create queries. But I faced a problem when I have to use a parameter recieved from a client:

```
private fun accountInfo(msg: AccountInfoMsg) {
        transaction {
            val accountInfo = UserAccount.wrapRow(Account.innerJoin(Account_Banned).select {
                Account.email.eq(msg.login.toLowerCase()) and (Account.id eq Account_Banned.accountId)
            }.single())
        }
    }
```

So how to create a prepared statement or how to pass a parameter with possible SQL injection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exposed does this for you under the covers. Because it delegates this work down to a `PreparedStatement`, it's handled for you. If you want to sanity check your inputs, you should do so for business reasons, leaving the rest up to Exposed.

Edit: I believe [the source of `Statement`](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/14e3e3f21facb4e20332fc81b15fab825ccdd337/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/exposed/sql/statements/Statement.kt) in Exposed shows this in action. Delegation to `PreparedStatement` is all you need to prevent a SQL Injection Attack here.

Comment: Yes, I checked with `105 OR 1=1` and it looks like `WHERE account.email = '105 or 1=1'` in the final query